# Como esconder teclado ao sair do EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tenho três edittext, quero que quando eu clicar fora deles ou finalizar o preenchimento meu teclado suma. Sendo que são um fragment. 
Como fazer isso?

Meu XML com os editText.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_grey"
        android:id="@+id/cadastroAvaliador"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/colaboradoresAmc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:hint="Avaliador">

        </AutoCompleteTextView>


        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/contratadasAmc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Contratada"
            android:layout_below="@+id/colaboradoresAmc"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/colaboradoresAmc">
        </AutoCompleteTextView>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dataRealizada"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/contratadasAmc"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/contratadasAmc"
            android:ems="6"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:hint="Data Realizada"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerTipo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dataRealizada"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dataRealizada"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dataRealizada"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentTipo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cadastroAvaliador"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/cadastroAvaliador"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cadastroAvaliador">

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Quando eu clicar na área marcada/rabiscada queria que o teclado escondesse.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: @acklay não é isso que quero. Quero que após utilizar o teclado ele saia da tela.

Comment: E como você sai do EditText? Aperta algum botão?! Tem como editar a pergunta e explicar melhor, ou até mesmo exemplificar, ou até mesmo colocar algum código que acha relevante na sua pergunta?!

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta @acklay

Comment: Que área é essa? No xml que postou, qual é a parte que declara essa área?

Comment: É o   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentTipo". @ramaral

Comment: Esse RelativeLayout tem alguma coisa dentro?

Comment: Tem uma listView, já coloquei a ID para ela. Mas gera um erro. Esse contentTipo é onde entra a listView. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.app.IActivityManager.handleApplicationWtf(android.os.IBinder, java.lang.String, boolean, android.app.ApplicationErrorReport$CrashInfo)' on a null object reference @ramaral

Comment: Assim fica complicado dar uma resposta. Primeiro você fala que é fora, depois é numa determinada área, agora a área tem uma ListView. Em que ficamos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quer esconder o teclado quando clicar naquela área defina um OnClickListener para ela e use o InputMethodManager para esconder o teclado.

Colocar no método `onCreateView` após "inflar" o layout.

```
    RelativeLayout contentTipo = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.contentTipo);
    contentTipo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            hideSoftKeyboard();
        }
    });
```

Substitua `view` pelo nome da variável para onde "inflou" o layout do fragment.

Método `hideSoftKeyboard()`:

```
private void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(),
                                                   InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
```

Comment: O primeiro link que coloquei como comentário faria isso, mas sem a questão de clicar em qualquer canto da tela. Mas acho que ele não conseguiu adaptar, disse que não era isso; =)

Comment: @acklay Mas na edição da pergunta ele fala em clicar fora.

Comment: @ramaral realizei essas alterações mas não  mudou em nada. Editei minha pergunta

Comment: @LucasCharles a sugestão do ramaral resolve seu problema!